# CSS rules are ignored in table with many columns

Tags: html, css, width, html-table

I need to display a table with a simple crosstab: the first three columns contain group-level info with the rest of the columns containing sum values.

I have defined all the css styles for different types of columns, rows, etc. - but while the colour rules are honoured, all the sizing rules are ignored.  I specified exact width values for each type of columns - and they are all simply ignored.  I cut the table out into a separate file - and confirmed the results. I cut down the number of columns to a minimum - same result. I tested on jsfiddle - the same result. I tested in Firefox, Chrome and Opera - same result (I'm working on a mac, so no IE to test).

The jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/6d76s/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="report-holder" class="report-holder">
    <table class="report">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="customer">Customer</th>
                <th class="date">Date</th>
                <th class="slm">Salesman</th>
                <th class="product"><span class="item-id">1024</span><span class="item-desc">PEELED TOMATOES 24/796 ML (796 ML)</span></th>
                <th class="product"><span class="item-id">1034</span><span class="item-desc">WHOLE CDN TOMATOES 24/796ML (796 ML)</span></th>
                <th class="product"><span class="item-id">1040</span><span class="item-desc">ITALIAN PEELED TOM 6/2.84 L (2.84 L)</span></th>
                <th class="product"><span class="item-id">1115</span><span class="item-desc">KTCHN RDY TOM 24/796ML (796 ML)</span></th>
                <th class="product"><span class="item-id">1116</span><span class="item-desc">SPICED DICED TOM 24/796ML (796 ML)</span></th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="customer"><span>100307 METRO RICHELIEU INC</span><span>635 AVE. NEWTON, QUEBEC, QC</span></td>
                <td class="date">4 Feb 2014</td>
                <td class="slm">20</td>
                <td class="product">2</td>
                <td class="product">2</td>
                <td class="product">2</td>
                <td class="product">2</td>
                <td class="product">0</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here's the corresponding CSS:

```
div.report-holder { margin: 30px 0px; width: 100%; overflow: auto; }

table.report { width: auto; }
table.report th { background: darkGrey; color: white; }
table.report tr.odd { background: white; }
table.report tr.even { background: #f7f7f7; }
table.report td, table.report th { padding: 1px 3px; }
table.report td span, table.report th span { display: block; }
table.report td.customer, table.report th.customer { width: 200px; text-align: left; }
table.report td.date, table.report th.date { width: 60px; text-align: left; }
table.report td.slm, table.report th.slm { width: 65px; text-align: center; }
table.report td.product, table.report th.product { width: 100px !important; text-align: center; }
```

Why are the `width` css rules ignored and how can I get the browsers to honour them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your columns have a fixed size, you should use `table-layout: fixed` and a fixed width (not auto).

```
table.report { width: 0; table-layout: fixed;}
```

The width will be calculated automatically based on the widths of your columns.

Comment: This will not work, as the number of columns is determined dynamically when the report is run.  The table is created in javascript using data retrieved using ajax.  This data contains information about the columns.

Comment: The code above should work with more columns. Try it out. You can also calculate the sum of the widths and set the table width to a fixed value since you are generating the page dynamically.

Comment: It does work, thanks.  Interesting though why doesn't `width: auto` work?

Comment: `auto` and `%` values don't respect fixed column widths. Actually, `auto` does, as long as there aren't other constraints (in this case, the table doesn't fit in the container, so it is treated as if it had `width:100%`). Read about `table-layout` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Comment: Ok, I buy the "other constraints" part - but the width is still not set to 100% - it's much bigger than that and the scroll bar is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the table width to `auto`. Set it to the sum of the widths of your columns.

Comment: This will not work, as the number of columns is determined dynamically when the report is run. The table is created in javascript using data retrieved using ajax. This data contains information about the columns.